# What does the following return type actually mean

Tags: c++, reference

// C++ header files

```
      int& abc(int x)
      {

      }
```

And how the return value will be collected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Comment: This is a very basic C++ question. You should really read some book or tutorial first.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the given function returns a reference to int variable. You can collect return value in an integer reference.

you can collect value as follows

> int &val = abc();

Comment: Or just plain `int`. You don't store it in a reference just because it returns a reference.

Comment: yeah.. but in that case it will again do a copy !